# why recordCount didnt work on my code?

Tags: vba, adodb

```
Public Function cekUsername(ByVal usr As String) As Boolean
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM pengguna WHERE username='" & usr & "';"
If rs.RecordCount = 1 Then
    cekUsername = True
Else
    cekUsername = False
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

it's always return false Although there is one of data in the database

Comment: The cursor type impacts the RecordCount as much as the specific connection. You might want to read up on this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676701(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thank's! it's work, i just use adOpenStatic for cursorType

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
rs.MoveLast
```

Before you can use RecordCount, otherwise it will show wrong values